# How to pull selected value form long select options list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, select

My list has a very long list of objects like around 7000. I'm using the getOptionValue function to get the option value once the user selects it. It works but I get a violation since the list of options is way too long.

[Violation] Long running JavaScript task took ''

Is there a way I can get rid of this error for a long list of select options?

```
const getOptionValue= (props) => (e) => {
    let options = e.target.options;
    let value = '';
    for (let i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            value = options[i].value;
        }
    }
    props.setOptionValue(value)
};

const AdminEdmForm = (props) => {
    return (
        <select multiple onChange={getOptionValue(props)}>
            {props.List.map((item, index) => {
                return <option key={index} value={item.id}> 
                       {item.id}</option>
            })}
        </select>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and delegate this task of finding the matched object from the long list to web worker

Answer (score 0):

To @"get the option value once the user selects it", you can bind an `onClick` event handler for each `option`:

```
const getOptionValue = (props) => (e) => {
    const el = e.target
    el.selected && props.setOptionValue(el.value)
}

const AdminEdmForm = (props) => {
    const handleOptionClick = getOptionValue(props)

    return (
        <select multiple>
            {props.List.map((item, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={item.id} onClick={handleOptionClick}> 
                    {item.id}
                </option> 
            ))}
        </select>
    )
};
```

In addition, your codes can't meet the intention @"get the option value once the user selects it".